# Last if condition is met, but code doesn't run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a small texted based game in which the player has to guess a word. If the secret word is water and the player guesses barge, the game should display -Ar-e, because those are the letters that are in common and since a is also in the correct place, it is shown as a capital letter.

```
from random import randint

def lingo():
    
    fp = open("wordsEn.txt","r")
    words = []
    
    while True:
        buffer = fp.readline()
        if buffer == "":
            break
        else:
            words.append(buffer[:-1])
    
    secret_word = list(words[randint(0,len(words)-1)])
    display_word = []
    rand_num = randint(0,len(secret_word)-1)
    compare_word = []
    
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        if i == rand_num:
            display_word.append(secret_word[i])
            compare_word.append(secret_word[i])
        else:
            display_word.append("-")
            compare_word.append("-")
    
    print(secret_word)
    
    for i in range(5):
        print(display_word)
        print(compare_word)
        
        if compare_word == secret_word:
            break
       
        else:
            
            while True:
                guess = input("guess: ")
                
                if guess.isalpha() == False:
                    print("Only letters")
                elif len(guess) > len(secret_word):
                    print("Too long")
                elif len(guess) < len(secret_word):
                    print("Too short")
                else:
                    break
    
            for j in range(len(guess)):
                print(guess[j])
                print(guess[j] in secret_word)
                if guess[j] in secret_word:
                    print("I am in")
                    if guess[j] == secret_word[j]:
                        display_word[j] == guess[j].upper()
                        compare_word[j] == guess[j]
                    else:
                        display_word[j] == guess[j]
                else:
                    print("I am out")
                    continue

lingo()
```

Comment: and what is your question / problem?

Comment: this `display_word[j] == guess[j]`  evaluates to `True` (or `False`) - did you mean to do an assignment with **one** `=` ?

Comment: All questions should be minimal https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It is not quickly clear what the question is here. Consider trying to reduce the complexity of the question.

Comment: @PatrickArtner you that was the problem, thanks for the comment.